# How to add Print functionality in iphone /iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, printing, ios4

Can any one get me idea to work on custom printing Functionality which they have implemented in the iphone iOS4 using multitaksing and airprint.
In the popup controller they have added the settings for the getting the printer list ,instead of that there is any way to get the print directly with out going to their settings.(adding any static ipaddress for the printer from the code in UIPrintInfo).

Kindly get me idea to resolve this ..

Thanks in advance.